# Category name variable in array based on user input

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, variables

I'm wanting `category_name` to equal text that is input through the use of a custom field in the WP UI. So if I type `cat_energy` that will replace the variable below `$category_name`.

```
//Category loop
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $category_name,
        'post_type' => array( 'page', 'post' ),
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '6',
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The only answer I've found that seemed correct stated to use the name of the custom field, in this case 'this_category':

```
$category_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'this_category', true );
```

However this hasn't worked for me. Can anyone help me out please? I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got some help with this. The correct answer is:

```
$category_name = get_field('this_category');
```

Maybe that will help someone, someday. Hopefully my question made sense.